# Is this hadith translation correct?

Tags: hadith, arabic-translation

from https://sunnah.com/urn/1289170

It was narrated from ‘Uqbah bin ‘Amir that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
"If I were to walk on a live coal or a sword, or if I were to sew shows to my feet, that would be better for me than walking on the grave of a Muslim. And I see no difference between relieving myself in the midst of graves or in the middle of the marketplace.”

"sew shows" doesn't make sense, is it a typographical error? do they mean shoes?

Comment: It should be: sew shoes

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/sunan-ibn-majah-volume/sunan-ibn-majah-volume-2#page/n425

Comment: You should inform them about the typo and let us know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is actually including at least a typo,
as:

> أو أخصف نعلي برجلي

means:

> or sew (repair) my shoes using my own feet or to my feet

and yes they mean shoes.

So the translator possibly made two mistakes a typo "shows" instead of "shoes" and he translated:

> أخصف نعلي برجلي
>   sew my shoes to my feet

while hadith commentators (see for example [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=54&ID=2883) in Hashiyat as-Sindi on Sunan ibn Majah or [here](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-122096/page-4887) in at-Tanwir the commentary on al-Jami' as-Saghir) are addressing the extreme effort (opinion of as-Sindi and al-Manawi) and/or the possible injury by doing so (As-Sna'ani [محمد بن إسماعيل الصنعاني](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A) -who actually considered the other option as possible) as possible meanings and seem unclear on what the prophet () actually meant to say here.

See also a fatwa where the hadith was quoted islamqa #[6050](https://islamqa.info/en/6050).